# darknet_images.py doesn't detect any objects. Darknet YOLOv4

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet, yolov4

So I'm running the default darknet_images.py script in pycharm (the one from Alexey's github repo) and when I give the img path, the img shows but the bounding boxes don't. I tried to solve the problem but couldn't find a solution. I found that my predictions variable is empty(in the main() function:
`image, detections = image_detection(image_name, network, class_names, class_colors, args.thresh )` 
Just in case I am missing something, I'll print here the darknet.py code and darknet_images.py code.
darknet.py:

```
#!python3
"""
Python 3 wrapper for identifying objects in images
Requires DLL compilation
Both the GPU and no-GPU version should be compiled; the no-GPU version should be renamed "yolo_cpp_dll_nogpu.dll".
On a GPU system, you can force CPU evaluation by any of:
- Set global variable DARKNET_FORCE_CPU to True
- Set environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to -1
- Set environment variable "FORCE_CPU" to "true"
- Set environment variable "DARKNET_PATH" to path darknet lib .so (for Linux)
Directly viewing or returning bounding-boxed images requires scikit-image to be installed (`pip install scikit-image`)
Original *nix 2.7: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/0f110834f4e18b30d5f101bf8f1724c34b7b83db/python/darknet.py
Windows Python 2.7 version: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/fc496d52bf22a0bb257300d3c79be9cd80e722cb/build/darknet/x64/darknet.py
@author: Philip Kahn
@date: 20180503
"""
from ctypes import *
import math
import random
import os


class BOX(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_float),
                ("y", c_float),
                ("w", c_float),
                ("h", c_float)]


class DETECTION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("bbox", BOX),
                ("classes", c_int),
                ("prob", POINTER(c_float)),
                ("mask", POINTER(c_float)),
                ("objectness", c_float),
                ("sort_class", c_int),
                ("uc", POINTER(c_float)),
                ("points", c_int),
                ("embeddings", POINTER(c_float)),
                ("embedding_size", c_int),
                ("sim", c_float),
                ("track_id", c_int)]

class DETNUMPAIR(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("num", c_int),
                ("dets", POINTER(DETECTION))]


class IMAGE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("w", c_int),
                ("h", c_int),
                ("c", c_int),
                ("data", POINTER(c_float))]


class METADATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("classes", c_int),
                ("names", POINTER(c_char_p))]


def network_width(net):
    return lib.network_width(net)


def network_height(net):
    return lib.network_height(net)


def bbox2points(bbox):
    """
    From bounding box yolo format
    to corner points cv2 rectangle
    """
    x, y, w, h = bbox
    xmin = int(round(x - (w / 2)))
    xmax = int(round(x + (w / 2)))
    ymin = int(round(y - (h / 2)))
    ymax = int(round(y + (h / 2)))
    return xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax


def class_colors(names):
    """
    Create a dict with one random BGR color for each
    class name
    """
    return {name: (
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255)) for name in names}


def load_network(config_file, data_file, weights, batch_size=1):
    """
    load model description and weights from config files
    args:
        config_file (str): path to .cfg model file
        data_file (str): path to .data model file
        weights (str): path to weights
    returns:
        network: trained model
        class_names
        class_colors
    """
    network = load_net_custom(
        config_file.encode("ascii"),
        weights.encode("ascii"), 0, batch_size)
    metadata = load_meta(data_file.encode("ascii"))
    class_names = [metadata.names[i].decode("ascii") for i in range(metadata.classes)]
    colors = class_colors(class_names)
    return network, class_names, colors


def print_detections(detections, coordinates=False):
    print("\nObjects:")
    for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
        x, y, w, h = bbox
        if coordinates:
            print("{}: {}%    (left_x: {:.0f}   top_y:  {:.0f}   width:   {:.0f}   height:  {:.0f})".format(label, confidence, x, y, w, h))
        else:
            print("{}: {}%".format(label, confidence))


def draw_boxes(detections, image, colors):
    import cv2
    for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
        left, top, right, bottom = bbox2points(bbox)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), colors[label], 1)
        cv2.putText(image, "{} [{:.2f}]".format(label, float(confidence)),
                    (left, top - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                    colors[label], 2)
    return image


def decode_detection(detections):
    decoded = []
    for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
        confidence = str(round(confidence * 100, 2))
        decoded.append((str(label), confidence, bbox))
    return decoded


def remove_negatives(detections, class_names, num):
    """
    Remove all classes with 0% confidence within the detection
    """
    predictions = []
    for j in range(num):
        for idx, name in enumerate(class_names):
            if detections[j].prob[idx] > 0:
                bbox = detections[j].bbox
                bbox = (bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.w, bbox.h)
                predictions.append((name, detections[j].prob[idx], (bbox)))
    return predictions


def detect_image(network, class_names, image, thresh=.5, hier_thresh=.5, nms=.45):
    """
        Returns a list with highest confidence class and their bbox
    """
    pnum = pointer(c_int(0))
    predict_image(network, image)
    detections = get_network_boxes(network, image.w, image.h,
                                   thresh, hier_thresh, None, 0, pnum, 0)
    num = pnum[0]
    if nms:
        do_nms_sort(detections, num, len(class_names), nms)
    predictions = remove_negatives(detections, class_names, num)
    predictions = decode_detection(predictions)
    free_detections(detections, num)
    return sorted(predictions, key=lambda x: x[1])


#  lib = CDLL("/home/pjreddie/documents/darknet/libdarknet.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)
#  lib = CDLL("libdarknet.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)
hasGPU = True
if os.name == "nt":
    cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    os.environ['PATH'] = cwd + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
    winGPUdll = os.path.join(cwd, "yolo_cpp_dll.dll")
    winNoGPUdll = os.path.join(cwd, "yolo_cpp_dll_nogpu.dll")
    envKeys = list()
    for k, v in os.environ.items():
        envKeys.append(k)
    try:
        try:
            tmp = os.environ["FORCE_CPU"].lower()
            if tmp in ["1", "true", "yes", "on"]:
                raise ValueError("ForceCPU")
            else:
                print("Flag value {} not forcing CPU mode".format(tmp))
        except KeyError:
            # We never set the flag
            if 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES' in envKeys:
                if int(os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']) < 0:
                    raise ValueError("ForceCPU")
            try:
                global DARKNET_FORCE_CPU
                if DARKNET_FORCE_CPU:
                    raise ValueError("ForceCPU")
            except NameError as cpu_error:
                print(cpu_error)
        if not os.path.exists(winGPUdll):
            raise ValueError("NoDLL")
        lib = CDLL(winGPUdll, RTLD_GLOBAL)
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        hasGPU = False
        if os.path.exists(winNoGPUdll):
            lib = CDLL(winNoGPUdll, RTLD_GLOBAL)
            print("Notice: CPU-only mode")
        else:
            # Try the other way, in case no_gpu was compile but not renamed
            lib = CDLL(winGPUdll, RTLD_GLOBAL)
            print("Environment variables indicated a CPU run, but we didn't find {}. Trying a GPU run anyway.".format(winNoGPUdll))
else:
    lib = CDLL(os.path.join(
        os.environ.get('DARKNET_PATH', './'),
        "libdarknet.so"), RTLD_GLOBAL)
lib.network_width.argtypes = [c_void_p]
lib.network_width.restype = c_int
lib.network_height.argtypes = [c_void_p]
lib.network_height.restype = c_int

copy_image_from_bytes = lib.copy_image_from_bytes
copy_image_from_bytes.argtypes = [IMAGE,c_char_p]

predict = lib.network_predict_ptr
predict.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_float)]
predict.restype = POINTER(c_float)

if hasGPU:
    set_gpu = lib.cuda_set_device
    set_gpu.argtypes = [c_int]

init_cpu = lib.init_cpu

make_image = lib.make_image
make_image.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_int]
make_image.restype = IMAGE

get_network_boxes = lib.get_network_boxes
get_network_boxes.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int, c_int, c_float, c_float, POINTER(c_int), c_int, POINTER(c_int), c_int]
get_network_boxes.restype = POINTER(DETECTION)

make_network_boxes = lib.make_network_boxes
make_network_boxes.argtypes = [c_void_p]
make_network_boxes.restype = POINTER(DETECTION)

free_detections = lib.free_detections
free_detections.argtypes = [POINTER(DETECTION), c_int]

free_batch_detections = lib.free_batch_detections
free_batch_detections.argtypes = [POINTER(DETNUMPAIR), c_int]

free_ptrs = lib.free_ptrs
free_ptrs.argtypes = [POINTER(c_void_p), c_int]

network_predict = lib.network_predict_ptr
network_predict.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_float)]

reset_rnn = lib.reset_rnn
reset_rnn.argtypes = [c_void_p]

load_net = lib.load_network
load_net.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int]
load_net.restype = c_void_p

load_net_custom = lib.load_network_custom
load_net_custom.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int, c_int]
load_net_custom.restype = c_void_p

free_network_ptr = lib.free_network_ptr
free_network_ptr.argtypes = [c_void_p]
free_network_ptr.restype = c_void_p

do_nms_obj = lib.do_nms_obj
do_nms_obj.argtypes = [POINTER(DETECTION), c_int, c_int, c_float]

do_nms_sort = lib.do_nms_sort
do_nms_sort.argtypes = [POINTER(DETECTION), c_int, c_int, c_float]

free_image = lib.free_image
free_image.argtypes = [IMAGE]

letterbox_image = lib.letterbox_image
letterbox_image.argtypes = [IMAGE, c_int, c_int]
letterbox_image.restype = IMAGE

load_meta = lib.get_metadata
lib.get_metadata.argtypes = [c_char_p]
lib.get_metadata.restype = METADATA

load_image = lib.load_image_color
load_image.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, c_int]
load_image.restype = IMAGE

rgbgr_image = lib.rgbgr_image
rgbgr_image.argtypes = [IMAGE]

predict_image = lib.network_predict_image
predict_image.argtypes = [c_void_p, IMAGE]
predict_image.restype = POINTER(c_float)

predict_image_letterbox = lib.network_predict_image_letterbox
predict_image_letterbox.argtypes = [c_void_p, IMAGE]
predict_image_letterbox.restype = POINTER(c_float)

network_predict_batch = lib.network_predict_batch
network_predict_batch.argtypes = [c_void_p, IMAGE, c_int, c_int, c_int,
                                  c_float, c_float, POINTER(c_int), c_int, c_int]
network_predict_batch.restype = POINTER(DETNUMPAIR)
```

darknet_images.py:

```
import argparse
import os
import glob
import random
import darknet
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import darknet


def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="YOLO Object Detection")
    parser.add_argument("--input", type=str, default="",
                        help="image source. It can be a single image, a"
                             "txt with paths to them, or a folder. Image valid"
                             " formats are jpg, jpeg or png."
                             "If no input is given, ")
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", default=1, type=int,
                        help="number of images to be processed at the same time")
    parser.add_argument("--weights", default="yolov4.weights",
                        help="yolo weights path")
    parser.add_argument("--dont_show", action='store_true',
                        help="windown inference display. For headless systems")
    parser.add_argument("--ext_output", action='store_true',
                        help="display bbox coordinates of detected objects")
    parser.add_argument("--save_labels", action='store_true',
                        help="save detections bbox for each image in yolo format")
    parser.add_argument("--config_file", default="./cfg/yolov4.cfg",
                        help="path to config file")
    parser.add_argument("--data_file", default="./cfg/coco.data",
                        help="path to data file")
    parser.add_argument("--thresh", type=float, default=.25,
                        help="remove detections with lower confidence")
    return parser.parse_args()


def check_arguments_errors(args):
    assert 0 < args.thresh < 1, "Threshold should be a float between zero and one (non-inclusive)"
    if not os.path.exists(args.config_file):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid config path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.config_file))))
    if not os.path.exists(args.weights):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid weight path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.weights))))
    if not os.path.exists(args.data_file):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid data file path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.data_file))))
    if args.input and not os.path.exists(args.input):
        raise(ValueError("Invalid image path {}".format(os.path.abspath(args.input))))


def check_batch_shape(images, batch_size):
    """
        Image sizes should be the same width and height
    """
    shapes = [image.shape for image in images]
    if len(set(shapes)) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Images don't have same shape")
    if len(shapes) > batch_size:
        raise ValueError("Batch size higher than number of images")
    return shapes[0]


def load_images(images_path):
    """
    If image path is given, return it directly
    For txt file, read it and return each line as image path
    In other case, it's a folder, return a list with names of each
    jpg, jpeg and png file
    """
    input_path_extension = images_path.split('.')[-1]
    if input_path_extension in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']:
        return [images_path]
    elif input_path_extension == "txt":
        with open(images_path, "r") as f:
            return f.read().splitlines()
    else:
        return glob.glob(
            os.path.join(images_path, "*.jpg")) + \
               glob.glob(os.path.join(images_path, "*.png")) + \
               glob.glob(os.path.join(images_path, "*.jpeg"))


def prepare_batch(images, network, channels=3):
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)

    darknet_images = []
    for image in images:
        image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image_resized = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (width, height),
                                   interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        custom_image = image_resized.transpose(2, 0, 1)
        darknet_images.append(custom_image)

    batch_array = np.concatenate(darknet_images, axis=0)
    batch_array = np.ascontiguousarray(batch_array.flat, dtype=np.float32)/255.0
    darknet_images = batch_array.ctypes.data_as(darknet.POINTER(darknet.c_float))
    return darknet.IMAGE(width, height, channels, darknet_images)


def image_detection(image_path, network, class_names, class_colors, thresh):
    # Darknet doesn't accept numpy images.
    # Create one with image we reuse for each detect
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)
    darknet_image = darknet.make_image(width, height, 3)

    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_resized = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (width, height),
                               interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    darknet.copy_image_from_bytes(darknet_image, image_resized.tobytes())
    detections = darknet.detect_image(network, class_names, darknet_image, thresh=thresh)
    darknet.free_image(darknet_image)
    image = darknet.draw_boxes(detections, image_resized, class_colors)
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), detections


def batch_detection(network, images, class_names, class_colors,
                    thresh=0.25, hier_thresh=.5, nms=.45, batch_size=4):
    image_height, image_width, _ = check_batch_shape(images, batch_size)
    darknet_images = prepare_batch(images, network)
    batch_detections = darknet.network_predict_batch(network, darknet_images, batch_size, image_width,
                                                     image_height, thresh, hier_thresh, None, 0, 0)
    batch_predictions = []
    for idx in range(batch_size):
        num = batch_detections[idx].num
        detections = batch_detections[idx].dets
        if nms:
            darknet.do_nms_obj(detections, num, len(class_names), nms)
        predictions = darknet.remove_negatives(detections, class_names, num)
        images[idx] = darknet.draw_boxes(predictions, images[idx], class_colors)
        batch_predictions.append(predictions)
    darknet.free_batch_detections(batch_detections, batch_size)
    return images, batch_predictions


def image_classification(image, network, class_names):
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_resized = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (width, height),
                               interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    darknet_image = darknet.make_image(width, height, 3)
    darknet.copy_image_from_bytes(darknet_image, image_resized.tobytes())
    detections = darknet.predict_image(network, darknet_image)
    predictions = [(name, detections[idx]) for idx, name in enumerate(class_names)]
    darknet.free_image(darknet_image)
    return sorted(predictions, key=lambda x: -x[1])


def convert2relative(image, bbox):
    """
    YOLO format use relative coordinates for annotation
    """
    x, y, w, h = bbox
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    return x/width, y/height, w/width, h/height


def save_annotations(name, image, detections, class_names):
    """
    Files saved with image_name.txt and relative coordinates
    """
    file_name = os.path.splitext(name)[0] + ".txt"
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
            x, y, w, h = convert2relative(image, bbox)
            label = class_names.index(label)
            f.write("{} {:.4f} {:.4f} {:.4f} {:.4f} {:.4f}\n".format(label, x, y, w, h, float(confidence)))


def batch_detection_example():
    args = parser()
    check_arguments_errors(args)
    batch_size = 3
    random.seed(3)  # deterministic bbox colors
    network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network(
        args.config_file,
        args.data_file,
        args.weights,
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
    image_names = ['data/horses.jpg', 'data/horses.jpg', 'data/eagle.jpg']
    images = [cv2.imread(image) for image in image_names]
    images, detections,  = batch_detection(network, images, class_names,
                                           class_colors, batch_size=batch_size)
    for name, image in zip(image_names, images):
        cv2.imwrite(name.replace("data/", ""), image)
    print(detections)


def main():
    args = parser()
    check_arguments_errors(args)

    random.seed(3)  # deterministic bbox colors
    network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network(
        args.config_file,
        args.data_file,
        args.weights,
        batch_size=args.batch_size
    )

    images = load_images(args.input)

    index = 0
    while True:
        # loop asking for new image paths if no list is given
        if args.input:
            if index >= len(images):
                break
            image_name = images[index]
        else:
            image_name = input("Enter Image Path: ")
        prev_time = time.time()
        image, detections = image_detection(
            image_name, network, class_names, class_colors, args.thresh
        )
        if args.save_labels:
            save_annotations(image_name, image, detections, class_names)
        darknet.print_detections(detections, args.ext_output)
        fps = int(1/(time.time() - prev_time))
        print("FPS: {}".format(fps))
        if not args.dont_show:
            cv2.imshow('Inference', image)
            if cv2.waitKey() & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        index += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # unconmment next line for an example of batch processing
    # batch_detection_example()
    main()
```

Comment: Hi! could you upload the image you are trying to detect object in? Also, are you using default config/weight files?

Comment: @ShawnRamirez yessir, I'm using everything as it given in the repo. The img that I am using has the following path: data/person.jpg. If you look in the darknet_images.py at the parser() function(in the beginning), you''ll see that I use the default weights and configs.